# db2 Stored proc - usage of default null gives error

Tags: database, stored-procedures, db2

Consider following proc:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE XYZ.ABC
                      (
                         IN V1 DATE,
                         IN V2 VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL
                      )
    SPECIFIC XYZ.ABC
    RESULT SETS 1
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    NULL CALL
    LANGUAGE SQL EXTERNAL ACTION
    INHERIT SPECIAL REGISTERS
BEGIN
        DECLARE temp_cursor CURSOR WITH HOLD WITH RETURN TO CALLER
        FOR
        select
        //long query
        where  ((V2 is not null AND V2='abc') OR (V2 is null));
        OPEN temp_cursor;
END
;
```

This gives me error

> An unexpected token "DEFAULT NULL" was found following " V2 VARCHAR(50)".  Expected tokens may include:  "".  LINE NUMBER=4.  SQLSTATE=42601

I can't understand why DEFAULT NULL won't work in this scenario.

Comment: Not all versions/platforms of DB2 support `default`. Are you sure you are looking at the correct documentation for your version?

Comment: Yes.It seems to be version problem. DB2 v9.5  does not support default keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be version problem. DB2 v9.5  does not support default keyword.